# Is there a way to create executable file for UWP[C++/xaml] application?

Tags: xaml, visual-c++, uwp, exe

I am trying to find a way to provide .exe (executable) file without side-loading the application or going through microsoft app store publishing process.

Also if its not possible, which type of App platform provide this facility.

Comment: If you use file picker , you will see it cant get .exe.

Comment: Actually I want to know Can we generate .exe executable for UWP application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible for UWP applications. You must generate an app package and install it via side-loading (if you don't want to go through the Store).
You could create a WPF application (or many other types of applications, for that matter) to have an executable at the end of the compilation.

Comment: Yup, Discovered after reading all forums. Application can be executed using app package/installer. Regarding WPF I have a question, I have c++ SDK ready and want to build UI to integrate with it. Will WPF support integration with c++, coz according to my knowledge its C#/VB and designer support is no-existent with C++/CLI . Let me know if I'm wrong. Or if you have suggestions for platform suitable for type of application, Please do share.

Comment: I have next to no experience with WPF, but if you'd like to stick to C++ all the way up to the UI, you should take Qt (https://www.qt.io/) into consideration as well. It's a very nice, battle-proven framework and on top of that, it's cross-platform, so you can run your completed application on any kind of desktop operating system, not just Windows.

Comment: I came across many frameworks like these, but they are bit expensive. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: You are welcome! If you think I answered your question, please accept my answer!

Answer (score -1):

It is possible see this Microsoft article on vcvarsall.bat

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170

I wondered and found it. I also noticed in the App.g.hpp file of my program near the bottom the file a disabled code can be set in properties to allow for main() with args of course. This link shows vcvarsall.bat for Visual Studio 2019 but the file locations are the same for Visual Studio 2022 except use Program Files instead of Program Files (x86) for Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: That doesn't help one bit. If you want to target the UWP, you need to create an AppX package. You cannot run the application without explicitly registering its AppX package. Much of this can be done on the command line, but I will challenge you to figure out how to run the XAML compiler on the command line (or even just find the binary that implements it).